# Apache virtal hosts unreachable

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I'm doing local php development with apache and virtual hosts. For some reason my virtual host sites have stopped responding.

Chrome error:

```
This web page is not available
ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

Firefox error:

```
Server not found.
```

I haven't made any change to the server config or php ini files since I set them up, and the sites were working fine earlier today. This affects all the virtual host sites I created, but apache still seems to be running fine on localhost.

I've tried restarting my system (ubuntu) and checked the apache access and error logs. Attempts made to access virtual hosts are not logged at all (since the problem started).

I have no idea what's going on. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it, but I think it's handy for others' reference.

My router had re-assigned my IP Address (I have no idea why). Therefore the IP Address in /etc/hosts for those virtual hosts domain names did not match the address of my dev PC.

Solution: I just updated the IP address in virtual hosts.

Another strange thing is the router seems to have removed all the IP Addresses of devices not currently connected. In the past it has kept them  around even though they are not connected, but that's another matter and I should look into it (Well I think I had assigned them a static IP, but it's been a while since I've touched the router settings).

Comment: This seems to happen to me whenever I use different router (very annoying!). I replaced the address in virtual host to "localhost/myvhost" and it seems to have solved the problem.